# Functions with 3 positional arguments but a list were given

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I was having an issue with a program I created to integrate and finding the value of a function using a trapezoidal method and exact integration, then the value of trapezoidal method will be compared with the exact integration using a graph.

Here's the code that I write:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as ply
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Integration, Trapezoidal Method

# Define function to integrate
def f(x):
    return 2+5*x**7+4*x**2+2*x**5

def polynom():
    return [2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5]

# Implementing trapezoidal method
def trapezoidal (x0,xn,n):
    # calculating step size
    h = (xn - x0) / n
    
    # Finding sum 
    integration = f(x0) + f(xn)
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        k = x0 + i*h
        integration = integration + 2 * f(k)
    
    # Finding final integration value
    integration = integration * h/2
    
    return integration

#Exact integration

# Find Indefinite integral
I = ply.polyint(polynom())

# Find Definite integral
a = lower_limit
b = upper_limit
A = ply.polyval(b, I) - ply.polyval(a, I)

# Input section
lower_limit = float(input("Enter lower limit of integration: "))
upper_limit = float(input("Enter upper limit of integration: "))
elements = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))

#Sub_interval list
n_interval = []

# iterating till the range
for val in range(0, elements):
    sub_interval = int(input("Enter number of sub intervals: "))

    n_interval.append(sub_interval) # adding the element

# Call trapezoidal() method and get result
result = trapezoidal(lower_limit, upper_limit, *n_interval) #The *n_interval is used to unpack the list.
print("Indefinite integral's constant of exact integration is: ", I)
print("Definite integral of the exact integration is: ", A)
print("Integration result by Trapezoidal method is: ", result)
print("Error value is: ", (((result-A)/A)*100))

# Plotting the error and with respects to "N"
xValue = [sub_interval, 0]
yValue = [0, ((result-A)/A)*100]

plt.plot(xValue, yValue)
plt.title("Comparison of 'N' to Error Values" )
plt.xlabel("N value")
plt.ylabel("Error value")
plt.show()
```

The program gave an error:

```
trapezoidal() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to change the functions arguments while at the same time still uses lists as the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass lists as parameters, you don't need the asterisk (*).

Just do:

```py
result = trapezoidal(lower_limit, upper_limit, n_interval)
```

It will pass the `n_interval` list as a parameter for trapezoidal.

For example:

```py
def trapezoidal(x0, xn, n):
    print(x0, xn, n)

trapezoidal(1, 10, [1, 2, 3, 4])
# n is a list
```

will print

```
1 10 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It's still give an error value. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'. This can't work, likely because (as I stated in the question) the function has three parameters, meanwhile the functions needs to work with whatever value the user inputs.

Comment: @nurhadidd that's up for your function to handle. You can use `isinstance(n, list)` within your function to determine whether it is a `list` and handle it accordingly.